# Set permissions after RPM install

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I use this spec file to use RPM files

```
Name:           pack-agent
Version:        1.0
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        Linux Agent installation script
Group:          Utilities
License:        license
Source0:        pack-agent-1.0.tar.gz
BuildArch:      x86_64
BuildRoot:      %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-root-%(%{__id_u} -n)
%description

%prep
%setup -q -n opt

%build

%install
#install -m 0755 -d $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/agent
#cp -ap agent/* $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/agent/

install -m 0755 -d %{buildroot}/opt
#cp -a * %{buildroot}/agent
cp -a * %{buildroot}/opt

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%files
/opt
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%attr(777, root, root) /opt/agent/bin/karaf

%doc
%changelog
```

But after install the files are not executable. I need to start file insight directories tree. Is there anyway to add chmod command insight the spec file and use it to set permissions after RPM install?

Answer (score 11):

You can add `chmod` to a `%post` section if you wanted to but that's the wrong approach to the problem.

You should just make sure that the files are executable in the buildroot during the installation and they should remain so (with that `%defattr` entry) in the RPM and once installed (though that `%defattr` entry should be *above* the `/opt` line).

Alternatively, you can use the `%defattr` macro and `%attr` macros to have RPM apply specific permissions to specific files in the `%files` section manually.

See [Directives For the %files list](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html) and [Specifying File Attributes](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-anywhere-specifying-file-attributes.html) for how the directives work.

Example from the second link:

```
%files
%attr(-, root, root) %doc README
%attr(4755, root, root) /usr/local/bin/cdp
%attr(-, root, root) /usr/local/bin/cdplay
%attr(-, root, rot) /usr/local/man/man1/cdp.1
```

Comment: I recommend the last paragraph as well. Default everything to something reasonable like 644, and then make your executables 755.

Comment: The `%post` `chmod` would be bad because for many reasons, the biggest being `rpm -V` would fail saying the permissions don't match the RPM DB.

Comment: Could you please show me how I need to edit the spec file for the last solution?

Comment: Or you can chmod that file in %install section

Comment: Files are always with permission `-rw-r--r--.` Any idea where is the problem?

Comment: I added %attr(777, root, root) /opt/agent/bin/karaf but when I install the RPM package the permission is -rw-r--r--

Comment: Try `0755` instead of `777` and see if that works. But like I said you can also just ensure that the permissions are correct in the buildroot and then not specify any permissions in the `%files` section and RPM will leave them alone.

Comment: `777` by `root` is a ginormous security hole BTW... there *might* even be a warning in your build logs saying "nope!"